# I want to change the location of log file in weblogic

Tags: file, logging, directory, weblogic

I'm using weblogic(Oracle), and log files are stored in /logs/, which is under server directory. But because of the size of storage, I'd like to move it to other directory like /u02 or other disk.

Is there any possible way to do?

Comment: @Ravi sorry for late response.

Answer (score 0):

As per official document, you can change the log file name and location.

> 1. If you have not already done so, in the Change Center of the
>      Administration Console, click Lock & Edit (see Use the Change Center).
> 2. In the left pane of the Console, expand Environment and select
>      Servers.
> 3. In the Servers table, click the name of the server instance
>      whose logging you want to configure.
> 4. Select Logging > General. In the
>      Log File Name field, enter a path and filename for the server log.

**[Change server log file name and location](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/WLACH/taskhelp/logging/ChangeServerLogFileNamesAndLocations.html)**

**--UPDATE--**

Of course, you could also use log rotate option in weblogic, if it is not enabled. There are many option on **when** would you like to move/rotate logs. Since, you have issue with memory. So, ideal solution would be rotate logging when it reached to specific size. ***Please note, in this case you will loss older logs***

**[RotateLogFiles](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs91/ConsoleHelp/taskhelp/logging/RotateLogFiles.html)**

Comment: I can't change the disk partition, it can only take under weblogic directory.

Comment: @SehunPark This is the only way you could do.

Comment: I got some solutions. I used logrotate and shell script at end of the logrotate script with cronjob. @Ravi

Comment: @SehunPark ofcourse, but your weblogic should have by default setting for log rotate

Comment: yes, it has, but I can't change the directory under other partition, it looks basically can only accept the directory under weblogic.

Comment: what happens when you put another path? do you have an error?
In the worst case you can use a symbolic link (on unix)